# My SQL AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to auto increment a value on a secondary column depending on a another refrence column in MySQL.

Say I have a table as follows, which I need to auto increment the ID value depending on the GRP_ID

```
+--------+----+---------+
| grp_id | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| 1001   |  1 | abc     |
| 1002   |  1 | xyz     |
| 1002   |  2 | ijl     |
| 1002   |  3 | efg     |
| 1003   |  1 | hij     |
| 1003   |  2 | mno     |
+--------+----+---------+
```

Comment: You can use a trigger on insert. But for two auto increment columns, that's currently not possible..

Answer (score -1):

you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` it's defending last the insert auto increment id any table in your mysql db, but you need to `insert values first  reference table or column` in MySQL .bec
there"s the place for id

```
INSERT INTO table (id, grap_id,name)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID() ,' ', 'Value4name');
```